# REQUEST FUNCTION FROm FLASK

Tags: python, flask

I am using `request.form.get("name")` to get the value of an input whose `type=number`.

I then want to be able to compare so as to ensure that it is a postive number as follows:

`number = request.form.get("name")`

`If number < 0:`

`# Do something`

3. This gives an error as follows:-

`TypeError: < not supported between instances of 'str' & 'int'`

Doesnt the input field already make the said request a number?

what is happening??

I tried to compare two numbers, turns out one of them is being treated as a string.

Comment: If you mean the HTML `<input type="number">`, then it's only a hint for the browser-side validation. It has no effect on the HTTP request, which will contain a string like `name=123&othername=321`. You need to parse the numbers explicitly (there's likely some form validation library for that)

Comment: Yes, I do mean the input tag as you mentioned. How do i parse this input from the user as a number on back-end?

Comment: Like always, `number = int(request.form.get('name'))` (preferably, wrapped into a `try ... except`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML input types like `<input type="number">` serve only for client-side validation purposes and have no effect on what's sent in the HTTP request. The HTTP forms will always contain text, like `param1=123&param2=blah`. You need to parse the values explicitly:

```
try:
    number = int(request.form.get('name'))
except ValueError:
    # handle the error
```

For more complex cases you can use a form validation library, e.g. [Flask-WTF](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.x/quickstart/#quickstart).